# CSS animation runs laggy in Android

Tags: android, jquery, css

I tested transition speeds of my website on mobile.

Apple devices works fine, but Android devices do not.

- The mobile browsers of Android devices have slow transitions.

> Note : I am using Fullpage.js to trigger transitions.

Followings are my codes.

**Jquery (Fullpage.js / url, https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)**

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        var leavingSection = $(this);

            if(index == 4 && direction =='down'){

            $('.m-tu-bg-01').addClass('d-bg-img-show d-bg-img-scale');
            $('.m-tu-bg-01').removeClass('d-bg-img-hide d-bg-img-scaleLarge');

            $('.m-tu-img-01').addClass('d-bg-img-show');
            $('.m-tu-img-01').removeClass('d-bg-img-hide');
```

**CSS**

```
.d-bg-img-show {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
        -o-transform: translateZ(0);}


.d-bg-img-hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
        -o-transform: translateZ(0);}

.d-bg-img-scaleLarge {
    transform: scale(0.4,0.4);}

.d-bg-img-scale {
    transform: scale(1,1);}
```

[Check it out over here!](http://myriels.com)

Comment: I think it depends on the device system speed.

Comment: I guess you are also using `css3:true` in fullPage.js, which is the default one? Are you using scroll bar at all? It will be faster without.

Comment: @LaraBelle Yes, it definitely depends on the device system, especially Samsung Galaxy.

Comment: @Alvaro I used css3: true. However now I am using css3: false, but problem is same.